# Expected identifier caesar.c 1 error brackets

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]);
{
    bool yes = false; //Will determine any value that is not equal to zero is false
    int l = 0
    int length = 0;
    string text = ""
    //User input
do
    {
        if(argc!=2) //Argc is too when it is run with one command line argument
        {
            printf("Invalid\n");
            return 1; //main entry function
        }
        else //converts string to an interger
        {
            l=atoi(argv[1]);// converts the frist command line
            yes = true;
        }

    } while (!yes); //if yes is true


    text = get_string(); //Gets string
    length = strlen(text); //Gets length of string inputed
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]))//check if letters are in alphabet
        {
            if (islower(text[i])) //lower case letters
            {
                printf("%c", ((((text[i] - 97)+l)%26)+97));  //Translates from 0 to 26 so l + 26
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ((((text [i] - 65)+l)%26)+65)); //Translates from 0 to 26 so l + 26
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", text[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The error is this I don't know what is wrong with my brackets though.

> caesar.c:14:1: error: expected identifier or
>             '('
>       {
>       ^
>       1 error generated.
>       make: *** [caesar] Error 1

Comment: There is a `;` behind `int main()`

Comment: There's a `;` missing at `string text = ""`. Also, there's no `string` in C, I guess you're using the `<cs50.h>` header, though. Please always include the headers that you're using in your code.

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: Also a missing `;` at `int l = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in line, explaining each error.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]); // You ended this prototype with a semi-colon (;) here.
{                                  // You cannot define the function after a semi-colon (;)
    bool yes = false;              // false is not a valid keyword in C. (it is valid in C++, or with special header files)
    int l = 0                      // You did not use a semi-colon here.
    int length = 0;                // This is the ONLY line you got right.
    string text = ""               // string is not a valid type in C (C++? defined in header file?) You did not use semi-colon
```